# Creating exe from Python 2.7 script with rawpy library gives error and crashes

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use PyInstaller to create a windows exe file from the following code:

```
import rawpy
import imageio

inputdata = r"d:\data\DJI\tmp\tmp2\DJI_0008.DNG"
tifoutfile = r"d:\data\DJI\tmp\tmp2\DJI_0008.tif"
with rawpy.imread(inputdata) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(output_bps=16)
    imageio.imwrite(tifoutfile, rgb)
    print "file written"
```

I use the following statement on windows commandline:

```
pyinstaller test2.py
```

I receive an error while creating the exe file, but PyInstaller continues:

83444 ERROR: Assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found

and the exe file gives a runtime error when I try to run it and afterwards this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
   File "c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
   exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\rawpy\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
   File "c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
   module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
   ImportError: DLL load failed: Nem siker³lt egy dinamikus csatolßs·f³ggvÚnytßr (DLL) inicializßl¾ rutinjßt vÚgrehajtani.
   Failed to execute script test2
```

I understand that the rawpy library causes this but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Add to as source which used a external library ! Some `dll` is missing,

Comment: @dsgdfg. The rawpy library uses _rawpy.py, raw_r.dll and vcomp90.dll but these are all incorporated in the package created by PyInstaller. The error message is related to x86_Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT but I would know how to make sure that this file (?) is found.

Comment: My opinion is: Copy imported dll to your .py(meaning your_app)  directory. Import a library and replace all external source folder to your app folder. And can use this module(external dll source) from every where. Another problem is  can't import module if module include a submodule name startswith "_".  How to handle `core module` on `Objective_C`. Some library not work  with 'copy and paste method'. Need compile module on your machine. So are different a `.c` and `.dll` external library. This error not related your app(error in Pyinstaller)